# BEP-20 BNB vs. BNB

Tags: erc-20, metamask, uniswap, binance

I have ETH (BEP-20) in my wallet.

I understand that to transact with it, I need some amount of BNB for gas.

My question is, do I need BNB or BNB (BEP-20) ?

I wish to eventually swap the BEP-20 ETH for ERC-20 ETH.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to make transactions you need pay fee in BNB coin (not WBNB). In addition, Ethereum token not exist in BinanceSmartChain network, only in Ethereum chain. Provide more info about what exactly tokens you wanna swap.